# Dask read_sql_table returns no data

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, dask

I'm trying to get whole table into dask dataframe using read_sql_table method but for some reason I don't get any data in dataframe. I've been struggling and googling for a bit with this. Do you guys know what might be the issue?

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
url = "oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@server:port/?service_name=name"

df = dd.read_sql_table('my_table', url, index_col='first_columnid', schema='schema_name', head_rows=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Heh it turns out that providing amount of partitions solved this problem...